# What happen to Checkout document during a PC crash?

Tags: document-library, check-out, check-in

What will happen to a document that was check-out from a document library in SharePoint 2007 when the client computer crash? (e.g. Is the check-out forever lost? Is there a need to check-out the document again?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the client computer crashes that will not cause a problem. When someone checks out a document that just means it is marked as Checked Out by that user. The document can be checked back in by that user from another client computer.

Comment: So, can I assume that other user cannot access the check out document until the user check in the document from another client computer?

Comment: Other users can open a document as Read-Only while it is checked out to someone else.

Comment: Also elevated users have the ability to discard checked-out document and unlock document for editing to other users. In this case changes that were done by the user whose pc has crashed now are lost, but not because of crash.